# Do I have to clear customs in Italy if I am flying from Tirana, Albania?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, italy, albania

in 2019, I am spending 5 days in Albania (a nonSchengen country) and then flying into Rome, Italy for 5 days before going to the United States. I am a US Citizen. Do I clear customs in Rome after my visit to Albania?

Comment: What makes you think you wouldn’t?

Comment: Thank you. I’ve traveled between Germany, France, Austria, and Switzerland without going through customs and just needed to know if I needed to allow extra time for customs in Italy and Albania. 

Comment: Please do not post 'thank you' answers. The best way to thank a user for an answer is to accept it (click the tick next to it) and additional information can be added to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, not only customs, but also immigration checks.

Entering Italy from a non Schengen country, you are subject to immigration checks (passport control). Entering Italy from a non-EU country, you are subject to customs checks.

It is for your question irrelevant that you are a US citizen or that you are staying 5 days.

Comment: Well, his USA citizenship is useful only inasmuch as like many other nationalities, it means he doesn't need to apply for an Italy visa in advance.